# Can someone show a configuration of rubik's cube which is exactly 20 optimal moves away from the solved state.

Tags: rubiks-cube

It takes atmost 20 optimal moves to solve a Rubik's cube, was just curious to see the cube on other end of the diameter.

Comment: I believe the superflip is the configuration believed to take the most moves to return the cube to the solved state, and it can be solved in 20 moves. But I have no proof that it cannot be solved in fewer than 20 moves, and I don't know of any better ways of proving this sort of thing other than what essentially boils down to brute force.

Comment: Here you are: http://www.cube20.org/distance20s/